# Are these two approaches for function-creation the same?

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure. Trying out an exercise from "Clojure for Brave and True".

The aim is to make a `dec9` function that can be used as:  `(dec9 10)`
it will substract 10 by 9 and return the result.

Could you please comment on which "decrementor maker" you would write if it were you?

I am including the two styles and their repl result.

```
(defn dec-maker
  [num]
  #(- % num))


(def dec9
  (dec-maker 9))

--
user> (dec9 10)
1
--

(defn dec-maker
  [num]
  #(- % num))


(defn dec9
  [target]
  ((dec-maker 9) target))

--
user> (dec9 10)
1
--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(def dec9
  (dec-maker 9))
```

The code above creates only one function that and that function is bound to `dec9` and the same is used  for every consecutive call to `dec9`. However:

```
(defn dec9
  [target]
  ((dec-maker 9) target))
```

This runs `(dec-maker 9)` and create a new function for each use of `dec9` that is applied only once. Thus this isn't really using the features that `dec-maker` provides since it's pretty much the same as:

```
(defn dec9 [target]
  (- 9 target))
```

The idea of having a function that makes specialized versions of a particular operation is a nice abstraction method in lexically scoped languages. A good example is making a addon to a procedure..

```
(defn safe-fun [fun pred default]
  (fn [v]
    (if (pred v)
        (fun v)
        (default v))))

(def sfirst (safe-fun first seq? identity))
(sfirst '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 1
(sfirst "abc")    ; ==> "abc"
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to see that the second approach is wastefully creating a new function each time dec9 is called.